# Convert string to xml quick in java

Tags: java, xml, performance

I have an application that sends an xml string to an output stream. Before writing the content to the output stream I have to make sure that content in text node(content in node value) doesn't exceed a fixed length. For this I have written a sample code to grab the text node content which can help me to do the content validation. But I'm afraid that this sample code is effective since it's taking about .2 secs when I run it eclipse profiler(TPTP). I would like to find out if there are any better ways to do this to improve the performance. Below is the sample code.

```
 StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
     stringWriter.write("<node src='something'>nodetext goes here</node>");
     InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(stringWriter.toString()));
     try {
        Element doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(src).getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println(doc.getChildNodes().getLength());
        Node n = doc.getChildNodes().item(0);
        System.out.println(n.getNodeValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: try to explore other libraries like nano parser or other parsing technologies like Stax or SAX. Can't pin point to any specific tech. for you as very less context of problem is given here.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a vast performance improvement by reusing the DocumentBuilderFactory - creating the factory involves searching the classpath. Reusing the DocumentBuilder will probably help as well. However, the overall approach of creating XML as a string, parsing it, and then serailizing it again seems intrinsically inefficient and I haven't really understood your explanation of why it's necessary.

Comment: Here is what my app does may be you can suggest a better approach. My web apps sends an xml response to browser. I have to intercept the response to make sure that text content in the xml tags will not exceed a certain length. That the reason I'm trying to parse the xml string to truncate the text content if there is any. I can not change the mechanism that generates xml string. Can you think of a better approach?

Comment: I'm always suspicious of arguments that say "I cannot change X". Those sort of arguments lead to structural decay in software. I would challenge the assumption - but it's not my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SAX parser instead of the DOM. See [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) for an example.